# DirectX11 Move Object Matrix Order

Tags: c++, directx

i have a 3d object and i want to be able to rotate it and then move it forward in the new direction but my code so far rotates the cube and then when you move it moves it in the default axis and not the new facing direction my code for rotation and translate and the updateWorld is as follows

```
 void GameObject::SetTranslation(float x, float y, float z)
{
    XMMATRIX t = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_translate);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&_translate, XMMatrixTranslation(x, y, z) * t);
}

    void GameObject::SetRotation(float x, float y, float z)
{
    XMFLOAT4X4  tempRot;
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&tempRot, XMMatrixRotationX(x) * XMMatrixRotationY(y) * XMMatrixRotationZ(z));

    XMMATRIX r = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_rotate);
    XMMATRIX tempRotate = XMLoadFloat4x4(&tempRot);
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&_rotate, XMMatrixMultiply(r, tempRotate));
}

    void GameObject::UpdateWorld()
{
    XMMATRIX scale = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_scale);
    XMMATRIX rotate = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_rotate);
    XMMATRIX translate = XMLoadFloat4x4(&_translate);

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&_world, scale *rotate * translate);
}
```

so after the user input has been checked the gameobjects updateworld is called

i am thinking i may have the order or something missing from the multiplication but i am very confused why it doesnt move in the new direction

any advice or help would be great thanks

Comment: Just swap the rotation and translation matrix. You can read more about DirectX matrices in [one of my blog posts](http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/directx-and-matrices/).

Comment: yes i tried swapping the rotate and translate round but then it seems to rotate around the 0,0,0 point and not on the current position

Comment: If you have multiple rotations and translations, it is easier to maintain the entire pose as a single matrix which you modify by multiplying more matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Nico Schertler is amazing people!!!

haha he helped me solve my problem and for others who are struggling here is what i was told and how i solved it

i had to apply the new transformation to the current world matrix and then i sat for a while wondering why it wasnt working , i had to reset the matrix's back to zero in order to make the correct change to the next new transfomration

my update world code now has this added to the end  like this

```
    XMStoreFloat4x4(&_world, scale  * translate*rotate *world );



XMStoreFloat4x4(&_scale, XMMatrixIdentity());
XMStoreFloat4x4(&_rotate, XMMatrixIdentity());
XMStoreFloat4x4(&_translate, XMMatrixIdentity());
```

Comment: You may find using [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) which is a C++ wrapper over DirectXMath that provides a few more overloads.